Leveling a floor without a foundation?
I need some advice. I bought a house that is lacking a foundation in certain areas. Huge mess. I've decided to make it as attractive as possible (and rent it out) until I can tear it down and rebuild, 5 years approx.
The kitchen was built on a deck. It gets incredibly cold in the winter (dog water bowl freezes), and mice are an issue. It sags a little in some areas and is generally uneven. I was considering self-leveling compound/cement so I can dye/stain it, or put some laminate flooring on top.

Located in the high desert, so it's dry and gets below freezing a few times per year.
The room is fairly large, approximately 10'x18'
The walls are board and batten, really poorly installed, and mice are a big issue, so I'd like something that seals well and fills in gaps.

What ideas do you have? Does my self-leveling compound idea work? What should I know? TIA.

Please add photos
